# Cannot get value in associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which `var_dump($array)` produces

```
array(7) 
    { 
    ["*attributes"]=> array(4) 
    { 
        ["type"]=> string(6) "hidden" 
        ["name"]=> string(3) "hmo" 
        ["class"]=> string(12) "form-control" 
        ["id"]=> string(3) "hmo" 
    } 
    ["*label"]=> NULL 
    ["*labelAttributes"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["*labelOptions"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["*messages"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["*options"]=> array(1) 
    { 
        ["disable_inarray_validator"]=> bool(true) 
    } 
    ["*value"]=> string(243) "{"My-Office":{"Floor":"New - ","Walls":"New - ","Door":"New - ","Switches":"New - ","Table":"New - ","Chair":"New - "},"Other office":{"Floor":"New - ","Walls":"New - ","Door":"New - ","Switches":"New - ","Table":"New - ","Chair":"New - "}}" 
   }
```

I am trying to access the json string in the last position (*value) but I cannot access it using `$array['*value']` as I get nothing returned. If I `var_dump($array['*value'])` I get NULL. Has anyone any idea why `$array['*value']` does not give me the string I require?

Comment: It looks to be a multidimensional array with the JSON deeper than you think. Let's see if editing the array makes this clearer.

Comment: Are you really dumping a array or an object? Why are `*` in the field names? (private properties?)

Comment: have you tried $array[6] ?

Comment: I'm half expecting invisible chars in those keys...

Comment: You should do a `foreach` on the array and `var_dump` both the keys and the values. Perhaps there is something strange happening with the keys.

Comment: Have you tried decoding the string directly from the array query: `$newArray = json_decode($array['*value']);`

Comment: Did you say you can access the other keys i.e. var_dump($array['*attributes']); ?

Comment: I have set up your array as per your results from your var_dump($array) and I can get the expected result for var_dump($array['*value']). It's just a string. I am running php 5.6.19. It's almost like its picking up the value for label which is beyond strange!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
array_values(array_slice($array, -1))[0];
```

to access the last element of the array $array.